# Gnuplot: Plotting from *txt files from different directories by reading column header

Tags: bash, gnuplot

My folder structure looks kind of like this

```
$ tree
.
├── Original_folder
│   └── cat.txt
├── folder1
│   └── cat.txt
├── folder2
│   └── cat.txt
├── folder3
│   
└── cat.txt
```

Each cat.txt file has 5 line before starting the column header. 
Sample cat.txt file is like this

```
Version LRv1.10.0
Build date 2017-12-06
MOL-calc
PRESSURE
!                       
      Time[s]     InletT[K]   InletP[Pa]   O2_GasOut     C_GasOut
       100         0.000885   1000000       0.0007       0.2111
and so on....
```

I want to plot first column along with the column which have column header with a keyword "_GasOut". (There are unknown number of header with this keywords, For each column I would like to have a separate graph). Additionally, the graphical results of Original_folder should be plotted in the same graph for all the plots from folder1, folder2, folder3...... and so on.

Corresponding graph should be saved in the corresponding folders.

N.B: folder numbers are not fixed.
I added one of the cat.txt file for reference. https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aoomvi55MLAQh1wMmpnPGnliFmgg

Comment: Sounds like you need a little `awk` script that when called with the name of a cat file and `column number` parameter of `0` tells you a list of the column numbers you want, and when called with a parameter of `N` gives you column 1 and column `N`. If so, consider adding the `awk` tag.

Comment: Could you show us the first few lines of one of the input and output files, rather than describing them?

Comment: All the input files (cat.txt) are like the file that I provided at the end of the Question. (Onedrive link).

Comment: Ugh! Are there no field separators?

Comment: Please untick the Dynamic word wrapping in the editor. All the columns are tab separated.

Comment: Is it fields 22-28 you want in this example?

Comment: No, from 28-35. But the problem is, I can not use column number as they are not fixed. (like plot p 'folder1/cat.txt' u 1:28, 'folder1/data' u 1:29 .....). I have to rely on the keyword "_GasOut"

Comment: 28-35 makes 8 occurrences, but `GasOut` only occurs 7 times in the posted file. Please check. Please also check the field numbers because I still make them fields 22-28. Please check here http://thesetchells.com/StackOverflow/a.txt

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

I don't know enough about `gnuplot` to understand the syntax of what you want to do as described in your comment. I have added code that saves the column headers and trims all the spaces and also code that derives the folder name from the filename - but I have no idea how you will use them so I just print them out. See the line marked `"FIXME"` in the code!

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk -F $'\t' '                                     # Using TABs as field separators
   /_GasOut/{                                       # On lines containing "_GasOut"
      for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){                           # ... iterate over all fields on line
         hdr=$f                                     # ... picking them up
         colhdr[f]=hdr                              # ... saving the column headers
         if(index(hdr,"_GasOut"))wanted[f]=1        # ... and noting which ones we want to print
      }
   }
   ENDFILE{                                         # As we reaach end of each file
      for(f in wanted){                             # ... iterate over wanted fields
         if(length(cmds)) cmds = cmds ",\n"         # ... adding commas and newlines if needed
         hdr = colhdr[f]                            # ... grabbing column header
         gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"",hdr) # ... trim leading or trailing spaces
         folder = FILENAME
         gsub(/\/cat.txt/,"",folder)                # ... deriving foldername
         print "hdr=", hdr, ", folder=", folder     # FIXME
         cmds = cmds "\"" FILENAME "\" using 1:" f  # ... and adding the "using" statement
      }
      delete wanted                                 # Forget list of wanted fields for next file
   }
   END{                                             # At very end of last file
      print cmds                                    # ... print accumulated gnuplot cmds
   }

   ' folder*/cat.txt
```

**Sample Output**

```
hdr= O2_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= H2O_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= H2_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= N2_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= NO_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= NO2_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= N2O_GasOut , folder= folder1
hdr= O2_GasOut , folder= folder2
hdr= H2O_GasOut , folder= folder2
hdr= H2_GasOut , folder= folder2
hdr= N2_GasOut , folder= folder2
hdr= NO_GasOut , folder= folder2
hdr= NO2_GasOut , folder= folder2
hdr= N2O_GasOut , folder= folder2
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:22,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:23,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:24,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:25,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:26,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:27,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:28,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:22,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:23,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:24,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:25,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:26,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:27,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:28
```

**Original Answer**

I can't seem to count fields the same way as you do, but here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

gawk -F $'\t' '                                     # Using TABs as field separators
   /_GasOut/{                                       # On lines containing "_GasOut"
      for(f=1;f<=NF;f++){                           # ... iterate over all fields on line
         this=$f                                    # ... picking them up
         if(index(this,"_GasOut"))wanted[f]=1       # ... and noting which ones we want to print
      }
   }
   ENDFILE{                                         # As we reaach end of each file
      for(f in wanted){                             # ... iterate over wanted fields
         if(length(cmds)) cmds = cmds ",\n"         # ... adding commas and newlines if needed
         cmds = cmds "\"" FILENAME "\" using 1:" f  # ... and adding the "using" statement
      }
      delete wanted                                 # Forget list of wanted fields for next file
   }
   END{                                             # At very end of last file
      print cmds                                    # ... print accumulated gnuplot cmds
   }

   ' folder*/cat.txt
```

And here is the sample output:

```
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:22,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:23,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:24,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:25,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:26,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:27,
"folder1/cat.txt" using 1:28,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:22,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:23,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:24,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:25,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:26,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:27,
"folder2/cat.txt" using 1:28
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. 
Another part of my Question was how to plot the graphs of the "Original_folder" together with other graphs of (folder1, folder2 .....). I mean I want to compare the output graphs of all folders with graphs of "Original_folder" So I need to put the graphs together in one graph.  
And how can I set the graphs name containing (columnheader + folder name). 
E.g Mole_fraction_folder01_CO2_GasOut.png

Comment: I have added more code to address your comment. Please have another look.

Comment: What I know is, to save all the outputs in a text file. Then invoke from bash script by gnuplot> plot "folder1/cat.txt" using 1:22, 
Running all the lines in that txt file can generate those plots. I individually ran those command (like gnuplot> plot "folder1/cat.txt" using 1:22, ) and it creates the graph. 
somehow I could not run all the output lines one after another.

Comment: Can you help me to write an out put like this...

`plot "Original_folder/cat.txt" using 1:22, \
      "folder1/cat.txt" using 1:22
plot "Original_folder/cat.txt" using 1:23, \
      "folder1/cat.txt" using 1:23
plot "Original_folder/cat.txt" using 1:24, \
     "folder1/cat.txt" using 1:24` 

and so on

Answer (score 0):

This can be done entirely in gnuplot.

I do not understand exactly where the script is supposed to find the names to match against desired column headers, but here is a simple gnuplot script that works for a single known column header, followed by a slightly more complicated script that assumes you have collected the desired names into an array of strings.

```
set term pdf
set key autotitle columnheader   # not strictly necessary but ensures the program
                                 # interprets the first line of data as headers
HEADER = "_GasOut"
orig = "original_folder/cat.txt"
do for [f=1:10] {                # 10 folders 
  in = sprintf("folder%d/cat.txt", f)
  out = sprintf("folder%d/plot.pdf")
  plot orig skip 5 using 1:(column(HEADER)), \
       in skip 5 using 1:(column(HEADER))
}
```

Now let's do the same thing except we add a loop over multiple column headers.

```
set term pdf
set key autotitle columnheader

array HEADS = [ "C_GasOut", "SurfaceT_cell7[K]", "O2_intMassFlowOut[kg]", \
                  "H2O_Conv", "InletT[K]" ]
orig = "original_folder/cat.txt"

do for [h = 1 : |HEADS|] {
  HEADER = HEADS[h]
  do for [f=1:10] { 
    in = sprintf("folder%d/cat.txt", f)
    out = sprintf("folder%d/plot.pdf")
    plot orig skip 5 using 1:(column(HEADER)), \
         in skip 5 using 1:(column(HEADER))
  }
}
```

If the names or number of the subfolders are not known in advance you could substitute the loop [f=1:10] with one that iterates over a list of folder names.  For example:

```
folders = system("ls -1 fold*")
nfolders = words(folders)
do for [f = 1 : nfolders] {
    in = sprintf("%s/cat.txt", folders(word(folders,f)))
    ... etc
```

Comment: I can not mention the Column header by full name like (C_GasOut) because this column name varies except "_GasOut" which is constant.

Comment: Gnuplot does not have regular expression operators, but in this case it is sufficient to use substring matching. See new answer

Comment: It's saying "warning: no column with header "_GasOut""

Answer (score 0):

This example shows how to plot all columns whose header contains the substring "_GasOut".   The strategy is to test each column header for the substring; if it matches then the column values are plotted, if there is no match then all values are treated as NaN.  `set datafile missing NaN` then causes the entire plot to be skipped.

I do not repeat here the iteration over subdirectories as shown in previous examples.

```
set rmargin at screen 0.85
set key reverse Left top left at screen 0.85, 0.9
set log y

data = 'cat.txt'
set datafile missing NaN

plot for [i=1:99] data skip 5 using 1:(strstrt(columnhead(i),"_GasOut") ? column(i) : NaN) title columnhead(i) noenhanced lw 2
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: I don't know why my gnuplot version 5.0 is considering "array" command as an invalid command!